# Is c.drive(); OK when Car* c is defined in main function for class Car

Tags: c++, class, oop

Suppose that in car.h and car.cpp we defined class Car and class function drive.

Then in the main.cpp, which contain main function:

```
Car* c;
c.drive();
```

Is this allowed? If so, what does this mean? I know that usually we write c->drive(); and what this means is well-known. But what for c.drive();?

Comment: No, of course not. Any half-decent compiler would tell you that.

Comment: It's generally a fair question to ask if something is valid even if the compiler accepts it, because there are many examples where compilers intentionally accept invalid code. But this is something that pretty much every compiler there is will reject, and testing would have shown that already.

Comment: *Any* C++ compiler will reject that, and you should already know that even before trying it, which you should already have done before asking here. -1

Comment: *"But what for `c.drive();`?"* It means nothing at all in this example; it's nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have declared a **pointer** to a `Car` object, **but have not made the pointer point to anything.**  It is in an undefined state.

Another problem is that a pointer is a discrete object and has no members.  Using the '.' notation, you are telling the compiler to access a **member of the pointer**.  Remember, a pointer can be thought of as a variable containing the location of an item; **the pointer does not contain nor is an instance of an object.**  Pointers have no members, so you should be getting an error from your compiler.

The resolution, for C++ people, is to declare an instance of the object:

```
  Car c;
  c.drive();
```

The resolution for people from the Java world is to allocate an instance in dynamic memory, access it, then delete the object:

```
  Car *c;  // Declare a pointer.
  c = new Car;  // Create an instance in dynamic memory.
  c->drive();   // Need pointer-to-member syntax.
  (*c).drive(); // Dereferencing the pointer, then accessing the member function.
  delete c;     // Delete the object created from dynamic memory.
```

I prefer the C++ method; simpler.